# for loop keeps gettging caught in an infinite loop

Tags: java, infinite-loop, openal

I copy/pasted code for an OpenAL sound loader from this tutorial: http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/OpenAL_Tutorial_6_-_Advanced_Loading_and_Error_Handles

However, whenever I try to load more than one sound, the for loop in the getALBuffer method gets caught in an infinite loop. I don't think I changed any of the code that I copy/pasted though. The call i.next() where i is of type Iterator seems to always return true, but I have no idea why. I'll post all of my copy/pasted code in case I accidentally change something without realizing it. The code starts by loadALData() being called.

```
public static String getALErrorString(int err) {
      switch (err) {
        case AL_NO_ERROR:
            return "AL_NO_ERROR";
        case AL_INVALID_NAME:
            return "AL_INVALID_NAME";
        case AL_INVALID_ENUM:
            return "AL_INVALID_ENUM";
        case AL_INVALID_VALUE:
            return "AL_INVALID_VALUE";
        case AL_INVALID_OPERATION:
            return "AL_INVALID_OPERATION";
        case AL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
            return "AL_OUT_OF_MEMORY";
        default:
            return "No such error code";
      }
}

public static String getALCErrorString(int err) {
    switch (err) {
    case ALC_NO_ERROR:
        return "AL_NO_ERROR";
    case ALC_INVALID_DEVICE:
        return "ALC_INVALID_DEVICE";
    case ALC_INVALID_CONTEXT:
        return "ALC_INVALID_CONTEXT";
    case ALC_INVALID_ENUM:
        return "ALC_INVALID_ENUM";
    case ALC_INVALID_VALUE:
        return "ALC_INVALID_VALUE";
    case ALC_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
        return "ALC_OUT_OF_MEMORY";
    default:
        return "no such error code";
    }
}

public static int loadALBuffer(String path){

    int result;
    IntBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);

    // Load wav data into a buffers.
    alGenBuffers(buffer);

    if ((result = alGetError()) != AL_NO_ERROR){
        throw new OpenALException(getALErrorString(result));
    }

    WaveData waveFile = LoadSound(path);

    if (waveFile != null){
        alBufferData(buffer.get(0), waveFile.format, waveFile.data, waveFile.samplerate);
        waveFile.dispose();
    }else{
        throw new RuntimeException("No such file: " + path);
    }

    // Do another error check and return.
    if ((result = alGetError()) != AL_NO_ERROR) {
        throw new OpenALException(getALErrorString(result));
    }

    return buffer.get(0);
}

/**
 * 1) Checks if file has already been loaded.
 * 2) If it has been loaded already, return the buffer id.
 * 3) If it has not been loaded, load it and return buffer id.
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public static int getLoadedALBuffer(String path) {
    int count = 0;
    for (Iterator i = loadedFiles.iterator(); i.hasNext(); count++) {
        if (i.equals(path)) {
            return ((Integer) buffers.get(count)).intValue();
        }
        //I added this if statement to catch the infinite loop
        if (count>=100000){
            System.out.println("getLoadedALBuffer was caught in an infinite loop!");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    int buffer = loadALBuffer(path);

    buffers.add(new Integer(buffer));
    loadedFiles.add(path);

    return buffer;
}

/**
 * 1) Creates a source.
 * 2) Calls 'GetLoadedALBuffer' with 'path' and uses the returned buffer id as it's sources buffer.
 * 3) Returns the source id.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static int loadALSample(String path, boolean loop) {
    IntBuffer source = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
    int buffer;
    int result;

    // Get the files buffer id (load it if necessary).
    buffer = getLoadedALBuffer(path);

    //I added this to handle infinite loop error
    if (buffer == -1){
        return -1;
    }

    // Generate a source.
    alGenSources(source);

    if ((result = alGetError()) != AL_NO_ERROR)
        throw new OpenALException(getALErrorString(result));

    // Setup the source properties.
    alSourcei(source.get(0), AL_BUFFER, buffer);
    alSourcef(source.get(0), AL_PITCH, 1.0f);
    alSourcef(source.get(0), AL_GAIN, 1.0f);
    //alSource(source.get(0), AL_POSITION, sourcePos);
    //alSource(source.get(0), AL_VELOCITY, sourceVel);
    alSourcei(source.get(0), AL_LOOPING, (loop ? AL_TRUE : AL_FALSE));

    // Save the source id.
    sources.add(new Integer(source.get(0)));

    // Return the source id.
    return source.get(0);
}

//I created this method
public static int LoadWaveFile(String name, int location, boolean loop){
    return loadALSample(getWaveFilePath(name,location), loop);
}

/**
 * 1) Releases temporary loading phase data.
 */
public static void killALLoadedData() {
    loadedFiles.clear();
}

// Source id's.
public static int busterShot;
public static int lifeGain;

public static void loadALData() {
    // Anything for your application here. No worrying about buffers.
    busterShot = LoadWaveFile("MM_Shoot", SFX_FOLDER, false);
    lifeGain = LoadWaveFile("MM_1up", SFX_FOLDER, false);

    killALLoadedData();
}

//I created these integers
public static final int MUSIC_FOLDER = 0;
public static final int SFX_FOLDER = 1;
//I created this method
public static WaveData LoadSound(String path){
    System.out.println("\nLoadSound() called!");
    WaveData sound = null;
    try {
        sound = WaveData.create(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path)));
        System.out.println(path+((sound!=null) ? " exists!" : " does not exist!"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sound;
}
//I created this method
public static WaveData QuickLoad(String name, int location){
    WaveData sound = LoadSound(getWaveFilePath(name, location));
    return sound;
}
//I created this Method
public static String getWaveFilePath(String name, int location){
    if (location == MUSIC_FOLDER){
        return "res/sounds/music/"+name+".wav";
    }else if(location == SFX_FOLDER){
        return "res/sounds/soundEffects/"+name+".wav";
    }

    return null;
}
```

EDIT: here is my console output when I run this code:

LoadSound() called!

res/sounds/soundEffects/MM_Shoot.wav exists!

getLoadedALBuffer was caught in an infinite loop!

Comment: Have you tried incrementing the iterator instead of the count variable in the for loop?

Comment: @fingaz oh, duhh! Wow that's an error on the official OpenAL website's own tutorial! Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Just gunna post as an answer. Upvote if you can!

Answer (score 1):

Increment the iterator as such:

```
for(Iterator i = ... ; i.hasNext(); i.next())
```

Comment: Don't you mean i.next()?

Comment: Oops! That's my c++ coming out. Thanks @AmirAfghani

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that even though the Iterator's number of elements increases with more wave data files being added, the for loop never increases to different elements of the Iterator.

That is a programming problem on the official lwjgl website's own tutorial! I did not expect that, hence my confusion. Honestly though I should of seen that error earlier. I'm sorry for the stupid question!